# Animated pictures on a website

Tags: html, css

How easy is it to animate 5 pictures/photos?

E.g. http://artyougrewupwith.com/

[image]

What's the best language(s) to use to do this effect?

Regards

Tea

Answer (score 1):

You could either do an animated gif (which is rather old technology), or you could javascript to set a timer to switch the image sources. I would recommend using javascript code. Here is a sample:

```
var i=0;
var imageSrcs=['image1.png','image3.png','image3.png','image4.png','image5.png'];
var imageElement=document.getElementById('imageToAnimate');
setInterval(
   function(){
      imageElement.src=imageSrcs[i];
      i=(i+1)%(imageSrcs.length+1);
   },1000)//Every 1000 milliseconds
```

This will cycle through the images in the array at a rate of 1/sec and will repeat once it reaches the end.

Comment: +1 for the JavaScript solution, I do not know so much about the Animated GIF option though. That is some pretty old technology you are referencing.

Comment: @Aaron Brewer I agree that gif is probably a bad idea (updated my answer), but I wanted to give the asker a variety of options.

Comment: how would I implement this javascript into the HTML page?  I assume this script would be in the header.  How about positioning it where I want to on the web page, e.g at the top of the website?

Comment: @TeaDrinkingGeek You would actually probably want it in a script tag after the image to animate to make sure the image has been created before the javascript is called, otherwise, you will encounter errors.

Comment: Sorry I don't know much javascript.  How would I call it?

Comment: That javascript will automatically start running as soon as the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to do this (not counting Flash):

**JavaScript:**

Probably the most common way to do it today would be to use JavaScript. Writing it from scratch on your own might take some time, especially if you are not used to writing JavaScript. However, if you are okay with using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), there are plenty of plugins that does exactly that.

Here is one example:

- http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

**CSS**

With CSS becoming increasingly more powerful through the features added with CSS3, it is also possible to accomplish a slideshow with that. Smashing Magazine has [an article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/) on how it can be achieved. Here's [an example](http://www.alessioatzeni.com/CSS3-Cycle-Image-Slider/) of what that could look like.

The drawback with this solution is a limited browser support for the new CSS-features.

Comment: I don't understand why this is answer is voted down. It clearly answers the posters question. The best language to do the effect is JavaScript, or by using a JavaScript library like jQuery. The image used in the question clearly states a "slider" or an "image rotator".

Comment: I agree. This answers the question. Nivo slider makes it easy...to answer the question. "how easy is it?" It's easy with nivo slider.